# Linux Bash script isnt printing out correctly

Tags: linux, bash

GOAL: My goal in this assignment is to create a script that will take in a student id as an input and will output a matching student's name OR an error message saying there is none by that name in this class. Im fairly new to Linux and it is kinda tough for me but I would love all the help I can get. Thanks!

[Screenshot Page 1 of assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG97i.png)

[Screenshot Page 2 of assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX4gx.png)

My script is printing off everyones name in the file rather than just the one I am searching for.

```
  #!/bin/bash
# findName.sh
searchFile="/acct/common/CSCE215-Fall17"

if [[ $1 = "" ]] ; then
  echo "Sorry that person is not in CSCE215 this semester"
  exit 2
fi

while read LINE
do
    firstNameIndex=0
    middleNameIndex=1
    lastNameIndex=2
    userIDIndex=3

    IFS=', ' read -r -a lineArray <<< "$LINE"

        if [[ $1 -eq ${lineArray[$userIDIndex]} ]] ; then
        echo ${lineArray[$firstNameIndex]} ${lineArray[$middleNameIndex]} ${lineArray[$lastNameIndex]}
    fi

done < "$searchFile"
```

Comment: Add a sample of input file so we can try your code and let you know if we see anything to fix.

Comment: The file that the names are read from is formatted as follows: Hunter,David,Hatch,hhatch  with a different person on each line.

Comment: `grep` would be great for this, your while loop is overkill.  You are processing all lines from the file, while grep will give you the matching line in 1 call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VERSION 3:

Here is how I would do it with grep.  This prevents you from looping through the input file.

```
#!/bin/bash

searchFile="sample.txt"

function notincourse()
{
    echo "Sorry that person is not in CSCE215 this semester"
    exit 2
}

# Verify arguments, 1 argument, name to search for
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "findName.sh <NAME>"
    exit 1
else
    searchfor=$1
fi

# Verify if the name is in the file
nameline=$(grep $searchfor $searchFile)
#if [ $(echo $nameline | wc -l) -eq 0 ]
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
    notincourse
else
    idvalue=$(echo $nameline | cut -d',' -f1)
    if [ "$idvalue" == "$searchfor" ]
    then
        IFS=', ' read -r -a lineArray <<< "$nameline"
        echo ${lineArray[1]} ${lineArray[2]} ${lineArray[3]}
    else
        notincourse
    fi
fi
```

I tried if with the following test input file:

```
111, firstname1, middlename1, lastname1
222, firstname2, middlename2, lastname2
333, firstname3, middlename3, lastname3
```

VERSION 3:  it now verifies that the id is indeed the first word in the line.  I realized that if the student id is someown included in his name (ya, but better safe than sorry!) my grep would return true!

Comment: That didn't output "Sorry that person..." when I put an incorrect student id

Comment: It did for me.  I ran it with arguments "111" and "4224".  Since I do not have your data file to try (or a portion of it), some adjustments might be needed.

Comment: Remember that `grep` is case sensitive.  If you need it to work for all cases, add option `-i` to the grep command.  Again not clear in your question + lack of sample data.

Comment: It output my name and everything when I typed my correct id, but when I put random letters, it just has a blank space with no return to console

Comment: What random argument did you give it?  If the shell just hangs there, it might be that you put a ' or a " in there.  Stick to letters and numbers.  Other characters are interpreted by the shell first.

Comment: This is a picture of the console. https://gyazo.com/d4879b72ea1e72b48126b62d2ec017e6

Comment: Change the first line to `#!/bin/bash -x` you will see everything the script is doing.

Comment: tms3@cocsce-l1d39-05:~$ ./findName.sh fsga
+ searchFile=/acct/common/CSCE215-Fall17
+ '[' 1 -ne 1 ']'
+ searchfor=fsga
++ grep -i fsga /acct/common/CSCE215-Fall17
+ nameline=
++ echo
++ wc -l
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ IFS=', '
+ read -r -a lineArray
+ echo

Comment: I also need the program to return an error message if the command line arguments are not equal to 1. WHere would that need to go

Comment: ok i fixed it, sorry for this.  1) if you try ./findName.sh with more (or less) than one argument, it will exit 2.  That is what the first if does.  2) I should have checked the status of the grep command ($?) in my second if.  My mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much @Nic3500 You are a life saver

Comment: np, if it meets with your  need, please accept the answer (the check mark on the left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

One line of code to change:

```
if [[ "$1" == "${lineArray[$userIDIndex]}" ]] ; then
```

Comment: bigmacd, it should be in the comments if it does not solve the entire script.